# issue with the function running process in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function foo(){
    function bar() {
        return 3;
    }
    return bar();
    function bar() {
        return 8;
    }
}
alert(foo());
</script>
```

Question:

The result shows: 8, why not 3, when script runs to this line: `return bar();` it should jump out of the `function foo(){}` and will not reach the lines belows it, which is

```
function bar() {
   return 8;
}
```

right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those function definitions are [*hoisted*](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/), that is, they appear in source order, only they act like they are all pulled to the top of the scope they're defined in.

After knowing this, you can tell the second one clobbers the first's definition.